GCP Composer 2 is not propagating variables to Airflow cluster
I set up a few Composer 2 environments via Terraform.
I understand that there is a difference between Composer environment variables and Airflow environment variables.
However, I've seen from some sources, even Google's issue tracker that prefixing environment variables with AIRFLOW_VAR_ should make composer propagate them to Airflow
This is not the case for me.
The TF definition, with google provider version 4.10.0 is the following
resource "google_composer_environment" "foo" {
  name    = "foo"
  region  = var.region
  project = var.project

  config {

    node_config {
      # elided
    }

    software_config {

      airflow_config_overrides = {
        # elided
      }

      image_version = "composer-2.6.6-airflow-2.7.3"

      env_variables = {
        AIRFLOW_VAR_env            = "staging"
        # elided 
      }
    }
  }
}

The composer env variables are being correctly added to the composer cluster. It's just the airflow variables that are not being propagated.
